# Transition matrix involving broken machine taking geometric time to fix

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

A machine breaks with probability $p$ and keeps working with probability $q=1-p$ on any day. When the machine is broken, it takes a random number of days $N$ to repair. N has a geometric distribution given by $P(N=k)=\beta(1-\beta)^{k-1}$. $beta$ is between $0$ and $1$. $X_n=1$ if the machine works on day $n$, $X_n=0$ if broken.

**How would you write the transition matrix?**

**How do you find the transition probabilities of the Markov chain?**

**What is $P(N\geq2)$?**

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of days taken to repair the machine is geometrically distributed with parameter $\beta$, when the machine is broken, it will remain broken with probability $\beta$ and be repaired with probability $1-\beta$. (This follows from the memoryless property of the geometric distribution.) The transition matrix is then given by

$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}q&p\\1-\beta&\beta \end{pmatrix}.
$$

The probability that the machine is broken for at least two days is given by

$$
1 - (\beta + \beta(1-\beta)).
$$

Comment: Does it matter which way round you get the transition matrix? Would having the $p$ and $\beta$ in the first column still work (with the second column being $1-p$ and $1-\beta$)?